# Working with files through binary representation

Tags: file, pdf, coldfusion, binary

So this question is probably horribly misguided, if it is please let me know what I need to know/understand or where I need to go to get this information.

So say I have 2 separate PDF files, and convert them each to a binary representation.

Could I combine those two files by converting the binary to a string and combining them?

Further, could I find and alter information as text by finding and replacing binary in either string?

Comment: The `cfpdf` tag might be useful for this particular situation.

Comment: *"Could I combine those two files by converting the binary to a string and combining them"* - no. Pdf does not allow that. *"could I find and alter information as text by finding and replacing binary in either string"* - only in very primitive PDFs  (uncompressed content streams, standard encodings, no kerning), and then only if the replacement has the same length as the replaced data.